# did my code is in a short-circuit way ( python3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

How would we adapt it to return True if at least three of the numbers are odd? Short-circuit the traversal when
the third odd number is found — don’t traverse the whole list unless we have to.
 ****I am a novice in python, I want to know the time is taken more when I use ==,<= operators why? did this code stop traversing after find the 3 odd?****

import time
start_time = time.time()
def d(x):

```
count = 0
for num in x:
    if num % 2 != 0:
       count += 1
    if count <= 3:
       return True
return False 
print((time.time() - start_time))
```

f = d([1,2,4,6,8,7,3,11,16,88,66,44,22])
print((time.time()-start_time),f)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right but I can propose some changes in your code. First - if you want to count number of odd numbers and return `True` if number of odds is `<= 3`. you can do it like that:

```py
>>> def count_odds(lst: list):
...     count = 0
...     for num in lst:
...             count += 1 if num % 2 else 0
...     return count <= 3
... 
>>> count_odds([1, 3, 5, 6])
True
>>> count_odds([1, 3, 7, 9, 11])
False
```

This function will return `True` only if there are 3, 2, 1 or 0 odd numbers in list that you've passed to this method.
On the other hand you can achieve your goal by using **break in the for loop.** Here is the solution:

```py
>>> lst = [1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> count = 0
>>> for num in lst:
...     if count > 3:
...             break
...     count += 1 if num % 2 else 0
>>> print("More than 3") if count > 3 else print("Less than 3")
Less than 3
# Rest of your code.
```

And another way to do it:

```
>>> def count_odds(lst: list):
...     result = list(map(lambda x: x % 2, lst))
...     return sum(result) <= 3
... 
>>> count_odds([1, 3, 7])
True
>>> count_odds([1, 3, 7, 9])
False
```

The map function takes every element of the **lst** list, then returns `True` if element is odd, False otherwise. Then the sum function sums all the `True` values of the **result** list and gives you the answer.